# texitem over y axis under specific position

Tags: python, pyqtgraph

I'm trying to position a TextItem on the Y-axis, but I can't find the relative position to the view in order to place the TextItem on the Y-axis. I was able to do this in another code, but now I'm working with multiple plots and view boxes in the same widget and the code doesn't work.

Here is the code that works with a single standalone plot:

```py
self.layout = QVBoxLayout()
self.setLayout(self.layout)
self.layout.setSpacing(0)
self.layout.setContentsMargins(0, 0, 0, 0)   
self.plt = pg.PlotWidget()
self.plt.setStyleSheet("border: none;")            
self.plt.setStyleSheet("QTabWidget::pane {border: 0;}")
self.layout.addWidget(self.plt)
self.y_axis=self.plt.getAxis('right')

 if self.text == None:
                self.text = pg.TextItem(html='<div>x</div>', fill=(255, 165, 0, 255))
                self.text.setParentItem(self.y_axis)
point = pg.QtCore.QPointF(0, y_position)
pos=self.plt.vb.mapViewToScene(point)
self.text.setPos(1.45,pos.y()-13)
```

This work wonderfully, but now that I had multiples plots it doesn't work.

```py
self.layout = QVBoxLayout()
self.setLayout(self.layout) 
self.win = pg.GraphicsLayoutWidget()
self.layout.addWidget(self.win)  
for t in list:
            
            if x == 3:
                self.win.nextRow()
                x = 0
            p = self.win.addPlot(title='')
            p.showGrid(x=False, y=True,alpha=0.3)
            p.showAxis('right')
            p.hideAxis('left')
            data =data
            self.data[t] = data
            p1 = p.plot(data['x'])
            self.curves.append([t,'p',p1])
            vb = p.getViewBox()
            vb.t = t
            self.update_rangey(vb,vr)

 def update_rangey(self,vb,viewRange):
        plot = vb.parentItem()
        y_axis = plot.getAxis('right')
        viewRange = vb.viewRange()
        vr0=viewRange[0][0]
        vr1=viewRange[0][1]
        if(vr0 < 0):
            vr0=0
        if(vb.t not in self.textclose):
                self.textclose[vb.t] = pg.TextItem(html='<div >x</div>', fill=(255, 165, 0, 255))
                point = pg.QtCore.QPointF(0, y_position)
                pos=vb.mapViewToScene(point)
                self.textclose[vb.t].setPos(1.45,pos.y()-13)   





i tried alot of workarounds bud nothing solved this, like 
'mapFromDevice', 'mapFromItem', 'mapFromParent', 'mapFromScene', 'mapFromView', 'mapRectFromDevice', 'mapRectFromItem', 'mapRectFromParent', 'mapRectFromScene', 'mapRectFromView', 'mapRectToDevice', 'mapRectToItem', 'mapRectToParent', 'mapRectToScene', 'mapRectToView', 'mapToDevice', 'mapToItem', 'mapToParent', 'mapToScene', 'mapToView'
looking  for the right coordenate but cant do it,
```